# Grouping an entire data set and aggregating

Tags: r, apply, mean, tapply

I have a dataset of 20 variables `V1,V2,V3......V20` with 1,200 rows.

I want to average of every four rows in my data frame, i.e my output dataset should have 20 columns 
containing `V1,V2,V3…V20` and 300 rows containing average of data in group of 4.

I cannot use `tapply` as for that I have to input 1 variable at a time; I want to average all the 20 variables at a time.

Is there an efficient way to do this? I want to use functions from apply family and would 
like to avoid looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lapply` with `colMeans`

```
 set.seed(42)
 dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 20*1200, replace=TRUE), ncol=20))
 n <- seq_len(nrow(dat))

 res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(dat, (n-1)%/%4 +1),colMeans, na.rm=TRUE))
 dim(res)
 #[1] 300  20
```

#### Explanation

Here the idea is to create a grouping variable that splits the datasets into subsets of datasets in a list with the condition that `1:4` rows goes into first subset, `5:8` to 2nd subset, and ..., the last subset would have `297:300`.  For easy understanding, using a subset of rows.  Suppose if your dataset has 10 rows:

```
  n1 <- seq_len(10)
  n1
  #[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

  (n1-1) %/%4 #created a numeric index to split by group
  # [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2
```

I added `1` to the above to start from `1` instead of `0`

```
  (n1-1) %/%4 +1
  #[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3
```

You could also use `gl` ie.

```
 gl(10, 4, 10)
```

For the dataset, it should be

```
 gl(1200, 4, 1200)
```

Now, you can either `split` `n1` by the newly created grouping index or the dataset

```
  split(n1,(n1-1) %/%4 +1) # you can check the result of this
```

For a subset of 10 rows of the `dataset`

```
  split(dat[1:10,], (n1-1) %/%4 +1)
```

and then use `lapply` along with `colMeans` to get the column means of each list element and rbind them using `do.call(rbind,..)`

#### Or

`summarise_each` from `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
  res2 <- dat %>% 
             mutate(N= (row_number()-1)%/%4+1) %>%
             group_by(N) %>%
             summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE))) %>% 
             select(-N) 

   dim(res2)
  #[1] 300  20

  all.equal(as.data.frame(res), as.data.frame(res2), check.attributes=FALSE)
  #[1] TRUE
```

#### Or

Using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
  DT1 <- setDT(dat)[, N:=(seq_len(.N)-1)%/%4 +1][,
            lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=N][,N:=NULL]
 dim(DT1)
#[1] 300  20
```

Comment: can u please explain me the use of %  in "(seq_len(.N)-1)%/%4 +1" or "mean(., na.rm=TRUE))) %>% " i never used "%" and have qualms because of that .

Comment: especially in this line "  DT1 <- setDT(dat)[, N:=(seq_len(.N)-1)%/%4 +1]" why do you add 1 at the end ?

Comment: @user197393 `1` is not necessary as I explained in the Explanation.  It is just to start the grouping variable from `1` instead of `0`.  You can also use the function `gl`. ie. `as.numeric(gl(300, 4, 300))` to get the same grouping variable.

Comment: @user197393  A mistake, it should be `as.numeric(gl(1200, 4, 1200))`